# Azure App Service doesn't pick up changes in web.config

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm experiencing a problem with Azure and the `web.config` file from time to time. The problem is that when I make some changes to the `web.config` file and deploy it to Azure, the changes are not picked up by the Azure App Service before restarting the web app.

I have visited Kudu to verify that it's not my deployment process that is broken. The changes are deployed to the app service on Azure. This is backed up by the fact that the changes get visible on the website after a restart of the app service.

Does anyone know what could cause this? The behavior is not consistent since the changes are sometimes visible right away (without a restart). As I understand the documentation, Azure should automatically pick up any changes and recycle the app service if needed.

I'm not sure if it makes any difference, but in my case, the changes I make are for the CSP:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="..." />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Tell us about your deployment process. A normal deployment will recycle the app service on its own.

Comment: The deployment is set up using Azure DevOps Pipelines using the *Deploy Azure App Service* task. It normally works just fine. I don't think that the problem is with the deployment since all of the files are correctly published to the server. But you may be right that the pipelines should recycle the app service maybe. It was just my understanding that it isn't needed and it hasn't been a problem previously.

Comment: config changes definitely need a recycle because that's when those are loaded into memory

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll just do that. It hasn't been a problem before and shouldn't be required according to this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/500ed394-e652-48c2-bef7-769c6d34ceae/when-is-web-app-service-restart-required?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview. But since the deploy is to a staging slot, restarting isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt you be using appsettings.json

Comment: I am. But the `web.config` file is still perfectly valid and solve tasks not solved by `appsettings.json` :)